Updating variable every 24 hours
I'm trying to add 1 to a variable every (2 seconds for this example). Problem is, the variable only ever updates to 1. Am I overlooking something?
Code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


countvar = 0 # Var defined.

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    counter.start(countvar) # loop started

@tasks.loop(seconds=2)
async def counter(countvar):
    countvar += 1 # every 2 seconds add 1 to var
    print(f'countvar + 1 ({countvar})')

Output:
countvar + 1 (1)
countvar + 1 (1)
countvar + 1 (1)

Expected Result:
countvar + 1 (1)
countvar + 1 (2)
countvar + 1 (3)


Use global keyword to modify the global copy of your variable.
async def counter(countvar):
    global countvar
    countvar += 1 # every 2 seconds add 1 to var


While global variables can be read inside a function, any assignment will create a local variable (which will from then on overshadow the global variable), not update the global variable, unless you use global statement (similar for nonlocal).
Thus, the function reads the global variable as 0, adds 1 to it for the result 1, and assigns it to a local variable by the same name, which it then prints (which is why you are seeing the output 1); but the global countvar remains as 0, and the next output will follow the exactly same pattern, as nothing has changed.
Add global countvar at the top of your function to fix. With that, local countvar will not be created; assignments to countvar will assign to the global countvar, as you expect.

The issue you're encountering is due to how Python handles arguments and scopes within functions. When you pass countvar to the counter function, it's passed as a value, not a reference. Therefore, modifying it within the function won't affect the original variable outside the function.
To solve this, you can make countvar a global variable or use a mutable data type like a list to pass it by reference. Here's how you can fix it using a global variable:
countvar = 0  # Define the variable outside of any functions

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global countvar  # Use the global keyword to modify the global variable
    counter.start()  # Start the loop

@tasks.loop(seconds=2)
async def counter():
    global countvar  # Use the global keyword to modify the global variable
    countvar += 1  # Add 1 to the global variable
    print(f'countvar + 1 ({countvar})')

This should give you the expected behavior where countvar increases by 1 every 2 seconds.

No, Python does not use call by value as an evaluation strategy, nor call by reference for that matter. And the evaluation strategy doesn't depend on the type of object.
